# To find $\frac{d\mu^{+}}{d\mu}$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be the signed measure then find $\frac{d\mu^{+}}{d\mu}$

My attempt $\frac{d\mu}{d\mu} = \frac{d\mu^{+}}{d\mu} - \frac{d\mu^{-}}{d\mu}$

Comment: "Find" in what sense? That is, what sort of thing is allowed as part of the solution? The answer that's appeared tells you what $d\mu^+/d|\mu|$ is in terms of $d\mu/d|\mu|$. Does that count as 'finding" it? There's a simple answer in terms of the Hahn Decomposition; would that count?

Comment: Yea. Hahn Decomposition would work. I was looking at something like that only.

Comment: If an answer in terms of the Hahn Decomposition is allowed then this is very easy. If $(A,B)$ is a Hahn decomposition for $\mu$ then $\mu^+(E)=$ what?

Answer (score 1):

We have  $d\mu^+=\frac{1}{2}(d|\mu|+d\mu)$.

However, we know that there is a function $h\in L^1$ with $|h|=1$ such that $d|\mu|=hd\mu$

Thus,

$d\mu^+=\frac{1}{2}(hd\mu+d\mu)=\frac{1}{2}(h+1)d\mu$.

Thus,

$\frac{d\mu^+}{d\mu}=\frac{1}{2}(h+1)$ where $h=\frac{d\mu}{d|\mu|}$

Comment: How did you get $d|\mu| = hd\mu$ ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarRepresentation.html

The proof relies on the Radon-Nikodym Theorem. 

Notice that $|\mu|<<<\mu$ and thus the Radon-Nikodym Derivative exists. 

Then proceed to prove that $|h|=1$ almost everywhere and thus, by redefining on that set, you get that $d|\mu|=hd\mu$

Comment: Yeah. This is fine. I got confused by ' ... such that  dμ=hd|μ| ' part. Maybe thats a typo ?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that (even though the statement stays true since you can multiply by $\overline{h}$ on both sides

Comment: Also, the comment given by David furnishes what I see as a better answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

Let $\langle P,N\rangle$ be a [Hahn decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem) of the space and prescribe function $f$ by:

$x\mapsto1$ if $x\in P$ and $x\mapsto0$ otherwise (i.e. if $x\in N$).

Then $$\int_Afd\mu=\mu(A\cap P)=\mu^+A$$